# how to do multiple file upload in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload

I would to like to implement multiple file upload. I am getting this code only single file is uploading. How to implement multiple file upload

**Form Code**

```
$docupload=new Zend_Form_Element_File('docupload',array('multiple' => 'multiple'));
                $docupload->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_File_Extension('doc,docx,pdf,txt'));
                $docupload->setIsArray(true);
```

**In Controller**

```
if(is_array($_FILES['docupload']['name']))
                {

                    $params = $this->_form->getValues();
                    foreach($_FILES['docupload']['name'] as $key=>$files)
                    {

                        $file_name=$_FILES['docupload']['name'][$key];
                       $temp_image_path = $_FILES['docupload']['tmp_name'][$key];

                     $file_name=implode(",", $file_name);
                    $temp_image_path=implode(",", $temp_image_path);
                    ['tmp_name'];
                    $path_parts = pathinfo($temp_image_path);

                    $tem_path =   $path_parts['dirname'];

                    $path_parts_extension = pathinfo($file_name);


                    $actual_filename=$path_parts_extension['filename'];
                    $file_extension = $path_parts_extension['extension'];



                if(APPLICATION_ENV != "development")
                    {
                        $path = '/';
                    }
                    else {

                        $path = '\\';
                    }

                    $filename = $tem_path.$path.$file_name;

                    $rename_uploadfile = $actual_filename.$random_number.".".$file_extension;

                    $fullFilePath = UPLOAD_USER_IMAGES.$rename_uploadfile;

                    // Rename uploaded file using Zend Framework
                    $filterFileRename = new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array('target' => $fullFilePath));
                    $filterFileRename->filter($filename);
                    $form_data=$params;
                    $form_data['docupload']=$rename_uploadfile;

                    if($id)
                    {
                        $this->_table->updateById("id",$id, $form_data);

                    }
                    else 
                    {
                    $this->_table->insert($form_data);  
                    }
```

I am new to zend framework. Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use the $_FILES variable, it would be better to use the applicable Zend code, considering that you're using Zend as your framework:

```
if (!$form->isValid()) {
    print "Uh oh... validation error";
}

if (!$form->docupload->receive()) {
    print "Error receiving the file(s)";
}

$files = $form->docupload->getFileName(); // result should be an array in this case
```

Comment: I added that line.  But sometimes its uploading, sometimes not uploading. what is the problem?